RuntimeError: Distributed package doesn't have NCCL built in
I am new to python and I can't run the demo of this code.
https://github.com/12wang3/rrl
however I install every module that's need to run and also Install NVIDIA NCCL on my computer.
when I run code below in Terminal with PyCharm, raise a "RuntimeError: Distributed package doesn't have NCCL built in"
# trained on the tic-tac-toe data set with NLAFs.
python3 experiment.py -d tic-tac-toe -bs 32 -s 1@64 -e401 -lrde 200 -lr 0.002 -ki 0 -i 0 -wd 0.001 --nlaf --alpha 0.9 --beta 3 --gamma 3 --temp 0.01 --print_rule 

I really appreciate to help me what should I do.
I expected to show result of training demo dataset.

Does this answer your question? Or this? Or this?
